# How mysql works when using multiple columns on group by?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Well how mysql works when using more than a column on group by like:

```
select
    a.nome,
    b.tb2_id,
    count(c.tb2_id) as saida
from tb1 a
left join tb2 b on a.tb1_id = b.tb1_id
left join tb3 c on b.tb2_id = c.tb2_id
group by a.tb1_id, b.tb2_id
order by a.tb1_id desc
```

how mysql knows which column it will use to group the result set?

i thought that it would do it in order but i changed the group by to 'b.tb2_id,a.tb1_id' but it doesn't make any change, same result.

Answer (score 7):

`group by a.tb1_id, b.tb2_id` means group by the pair of `a.tb1_id` and `b.tb2_id`, both `a.tb1_id` and `b.tb2_id` need to be same to be treated as a group.

Comment: Best explanation I've seen so far

Answer (score 0):

Only the `order by` clause affects the order of rows.

The `group by` clause affects data aggregation. mysql is special in that, unlike most other databases, it allows the data to be grouped by columns not selected, and further allows non-grouped by columns to be non-aggregated. In this case of this last option being exercised (as in your query - `a.nome` is not being grouped by), mysql returns the *first* row encountered for each group. All other databases I know would throw an SQL syntax exception if you tried to execute this query.